# index Out of bounds - C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, indexing

OK i tried going through the code myself a bunch of times but the IDE- Visual Studio always says it's wrong..

INDEX WAS OUTSIDE OF BOUND ERROR

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //declare Arrays for buttons and 
            //LEDs

            int[] buttonArray = new int[4]; // Left to right .-..   ------ 
            //left, top, bottom, right
            int[,] ledArray = new int[10, 10];

            //declare variables
            int strandSnake = 0;
            int requestR = 0;

            int countDeclareButtonArray = 0;
            int countWriteButtonArray = 0;



            //code
            if (strandSnake != 1)
            {

            }


            //Declaring the four buttons
            for (int ip = 0; ip < 4; ip++)
            {
                buttonArray[countDeclareButtonArray] = countDeclareButtonArray;
                countDeclareButtonArray++;
            }

            // writing the four buttons to the screen.

            foreach (int ip in buttonArray)
            {

                requestR = buttonArray[countWriteButtonArray];
                countWriteButtonArray++;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, format your code and provide more information. Which line produces the error? Could you paste the whole message here?

Answer (score 0):

You should known index range of array in C# from **0 .. array.Length - 1**

So, if you have

```
int[] a = new int[4];
```

You can access **a[0]. a[1], a[2], a[3]**,

But when you access **a[4]**, you will got **INDEX WAS OUTSIDE OF BOUND ERROR**.

Debug it and searching where did error go from

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at code-snippet, Value of `countWriteButtonArray` variable is `4` so you have to assign `0` to `countWriteButtonArray`.

```
countWriteButtonArray=0;
foreach (int ip in buttonArray) 
{
  requestR = buttonArray[countWriteButtonArray];
  countWriteButtonArray++;
}
```

If you want to get an element from the `buttonArray` array then you can use:

```
 foreach (int ip in buttonArray) 
    {
       //
    }
```

Use for loop to iterate an array using index.

```
for(countWriteButtonArray=0;countWriteButtonArray<=buttonArray.GetUpperBound(0);countWriteButtonArray++) 
    {
      requestR = buttonArray[countWriteButtonArray];
    }
```